# Error integrating Adobe Creative SDK in Android

Tags: android, retrofit, picasso, okhttp, adobecreativesdk

I have found a peculiar issue and don't know how to get around it.

I recently tried to integrate Adobe creative sdk in by current Android code.

After its integration my application throws errors.

especially methods not found and class not found errors.

After a lot of digging i came to a conclusion that creative sdk uses OK HTTP library 1.60

This creates issue with Picasso and retrofit libraries which depend on a higher version of okHTTP to function.

I removed Picasso from my dependencies but i still found that Creative SDK uses Picasso too.

Somehow the version differences in OK HTTP library is the root cause of the issue.

Can anybody tell me how to instruct Android compiler to always use the latest OK HTTP library and ignore the ones which are in creative sdk.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question for anyone who faces this problem with Retrofit,Picasso and Creative Sdk used in same project :

please include the following when you are using the Image library of creative sdk in your project build.gradle

```
compile('com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks bro:) It helped.